# If value then value in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a translation formula (not sure what its really called) in Crystal and my formula is not working.

Basically the field can have 3 values and I am trying to convert/translate them to other text

```
if ({FIELD}="1") then "ABC" or    
if ({FIELD}="2") then "DEF" or    
if ({FIELD}="3") then "GHI"
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong and spent too much time trying to figure it out on google

Answer (score 0):

If you mean formulas then you should be using else if:

```
if ({FIELD}="1") then "ABC"    
else if ({FIELD}="2") then "DEF"  
else if ({FIELD}="3") then "GHI"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below

```
Select {FIELD}
case "1" : "ABC"    
case "2" : "DEF"  
case "3" : "GHI"
```